# Tauchart Transparency

Tags: r, plot

I have a tauchart as follows:

```
library(tauchart)
tauchart(dataset)%>%
  tau_point("Var1","Var2","Var3") %>%
  tau_color_manual()%>%
  tau_tooltip(c("Var4","Var5","Date"))%>%
tau_legend()
```

When this is created, there is a legend on the right hand side and I can hover over Var3 in the legend section and the others will become transparent. Is there a way to make the transparency 0 so that I can only see the Var3 that I select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `tau_add_css_rule()`.

This is a plain vanilla *taucharts* example:

```
#devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/taucharts")
library(taucharts)

tauchart(mtcars) %>%
  tau_point("wt", "mpg", color="cyl") %>%
  tau_color_manual() %>%
  tau_legend() %>%
  tau_tooltip()
```

The result looks like this when you highlight a subset of the data:

[image: xxxx]

But the stylesheet can be modified as follows:

```
#devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/taucharts")
library(taucharts)

exclusive_highlighting <- function(tau) {
  tau %>%
  tau_add_css_rule("{{ID}} .graphical-report__highlighted_chart .graphical-report__dot.graphical-report__highlighted {stroke-width: 2;  opacity: 1}") %>%
  tau_add_css_rule("{{ID}} .graphical-report__highlighted_chart .graphical-report__dot {stroke-width: 1;  opacity: 0}")
}

tauchart(mtcars) %>%
  tau_point("wt", "mpg", color="cyl") %>%
  tau_color_manual() %>%
  tau_legend() %>%
  tau_tooltip() %>%
  exclusive_highlighting()
```

which results in this when a subset is highlighted:

[image: tauchart with modified CSS]

So, in principle you can do non-standard customizations to the way these *taucharts* are rendered, but unfortunately one needs to do a bit of digging first to understand precisely how the CSS works and figure out what to pass to `tau_add_css_rule()`...

Comment: Of course, the dots in the legend also work as toggles, which is another way to hide subsets one is not interested in. But that does change the axes.

Comment: One more question, I can make it into a separate one to give you the option to receive another answer if you want but 1) Is there any documentation on these tau_add_css_rule() anywhere? 2) Is there a rule in which you can select a variable in the legend, and when you put your cursor back onto the graph, the other variables DO NOT pop up again? For my graph, I have over 100 variables and when I hover over one of the variables it doesn't have meaning because there are just too many. Thanks!

Comment: @analytics 1) Not that I know of... `?tau_add_css_rule` doesn't got into details unfortunately. 2) Not sure if that could be done, sorry :( Now I see: clicking each of the 100 variables to toggle them off one by one isn't appealing either...

Comment: Ok no problem. I'm just trying to figure out any reference for how you learn functions like: graphical-report__highlighted_chart .graphical-report__dot.graphical. I'll keep looking into it though. Thanks. @WhiteViking